# Socket.IO in NodeJS - emitting event from client-side doesn's works

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

i have this code by server-side:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(io){

 var router = express.Router();
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('monitoring', { title: 'monitoring-test' });
 });



io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log('test connection!');
    socket.on("SampleEvent", function (args1) {
        console.log('called Sample event');
    });
});


    return router;
 }
```

On the client side i have:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/monitoring')
 alert("alertbox1");


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnCallEvent").click(function(){
        var args1 = {user: "client1", text: "Hello, world!"};
socket.emit("SampleEvent", args);
    }); 
});
```

OnClick event works, and connection works too- after open monitoring site i have `'test connection!'` in console. But when i try to call SampleEvent from client side (after click button) nothings happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are connecting to /monitoring which might implicitly select a namespace/room called monitoring. Try connecting directly to /

```
io.connect('http://localhost:3000/')
```

And see if that makes a difference. And also, where do you add your socket.io to the underlying http server (express, in your case). It doesn't show in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use my `socket.io` on the server side, which works for me:

Set-up at the top of the file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Returning socket events:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('MyEvent', function(data) {
        console.log('My Event has fired and contains:');
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Then on the client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit('MyEvent', {EventData1: 'test', EventData2: 'test2' });
</script>
```